# iOS Restoring in-app purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an app where I want to implement in-app purchase for non-consumable product. 
Per Apple's in-app purchase guidelines, I have to provide option to restore purchases. Also in my app each user needs to register with an account, and this is what bothers me:

Let's say Jon Doe has registered in my app with account X and  made purchase, and on my server side I have created record of this. Now Jon  decides to create new account in my app - X1 and he decides  to restore purchases and he enters his iTunes password and everything is fine, but account X1 is not aacount X in my app, he should not receive this product again (for different account) based on same iTunes purchase.

I could not find anything in apple guidelines about this, so my question is can I reject restoring purchase for account X1 because initial purchase was made by account X even though X and X1 are actually same person - Jon (using different accounts in my app) but using same iTunes account to make purchase / restore purchase ? Will this fail on Apple's review ?

Comment: IAP is tied to an iTunes account. Period. There is no way to associate that with whatever arbitrary account(s) your app may maintain. A single user may install your app on several different iOS devices and create several different accounts through your app. But since all devices are theirs and all use the same iTunes account, a single IAP purchase should appear on all devices, despite using different app accounts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) So in theory my user Jon can have 10 friends, and tell them, give me your accounts, log into each of them, each time click restore purchase and they'll now have that same non-consumable product ? Am I missing something ? Is there no way to take care of this ?

Comment: I suppose, in theory, if each of Jon's friends let Jon log into their devices using Jon's iTunes account, then each of Jon's friends would get your app's IAP for free. This will be so rare you shouldn't waste more than 1 second worrying about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, this is first time I'm implementing IAP, so I ddin't want to do anything stupid, or overlook smth.

Comment: Just a follow up on this question. I have been thinking about this scenario, and I find this really strange. Are you sure about this, @maddy? What about let's say Netflix. If that would be the case I could purchase a subscription from my Apple ID and then sign in to all my friends netflix accounts and restore my purchase and give them all a year. That's not how it should work.